# COQ identity term which is not eq_refl

Tags: equality, coq

I am still wondering what it means that a term of the equality type `eq` in COQ can be different from `eq_refl`.

Is the following term an example for this?

```
((fun x:nat => eq_refl x) 2).
```

This term is syntactically different from `eq_refl`, but nevertheless it computes to `eq_refl`.

Does there exist examples of terms which do not compute to `eq_refl` ?

P.S. Its not a homework question ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you point out, `(fun x => eq_refl x) 2` is *not* actually different from `eq_refl 2`, since both expressions compute to the same thing.

Answering your second question is a bit delicate, because it can be interpreted in many different ways. Here's one possibility (which I think is the one you had in mind):

> Are there any type `T` and terms `x y : T`, such that there is a proof `e` of `@eq T x y` in the empty context that does *not* compute to `@eq_refl T z` (where `z : T` is the result of computing `x` and `y`)?

I believe that the answer to this question is no. It should be possible  to prove it formally by arguing that, since Coq's theory is strongly normalizing, `e` must have a normal form `e'`, and that all normal forms that have type `eq` must be `eq_refl`.

Note that, if drop the requirement that `e` is typed in the empty context, this does not hold anymore. For instance, consider the proof term of `forall n, n + 0 = n`.

```
Fixpoint plus_n_0 n : n + 0 = n :=
  match n return n + 0 = n with
  | 0 => eq_refl 0
  | S n' => match plus_n_0 n' in _ = m return S (n' + 0) = S m with
            | eq_refl => eq_refl (S (n' + 0))
            end
  end.
```

In the successor branch, we use the `match` to produce a proof of `S (n' + 0) = S n'` which does *not* compute to `eq_refl`. This happens because the `match` cannot reduce the `plus_n_0 n'` term, since it's a function applied to a variable. However, if we apply `plus_n_0` to any concrete natural number (say, `1729`), the resulting proof will compute to `eq_refl 1729` (try it!).

Another thing worth pointing out is that, when arguing that every closed proof of equality computes to `eq_refl`, we had to reason *outside* of Coq's logic, appealing to a normalization argument that we cannot phrase as a Coq proposition: note that, because Coq identifies terms up to convertibility, there's no way of writing a proposition `P : nat -> Prop` such that `P n` holds if and only if `n` is a Coq term in normal form.

Given this fact, you may wonder if there's anyway of establishing that result *inside* Coq's logic; that is,

```
forall T (x : T) (e : x = x), e = eq_refl x,
```

or, paraphrased in English, "every proof of equality is equal to `eq_refl`". As it turns out, this statement is *independent* of Coq's logic, which means that it cannot be proved nor disproved within Coq itself.

It may seem at first that this contradicts what I said earlier. But recall that we can always add new axioms to Coq's logic if they don't contradict results that can be proved inside the logic. This means that it is perfectly fine to assume that there exists *some* type `T`, *some* term `x : T`, and *some* proof `e` of `x = x` such that `e <> eq_refl x`. If we added this axiom, then the argument I gave earlier would no longer apply, since there would be normal forms of equality proofs that would be syntactically different from `eq_refl` (namely, `e`).

The fact that we cannot establish this result inside Coq's logic (and similar formal systems, such as Martin-Löf's type theory) is exactly what enables homotopy type theory. HoTT postulates the existence of the univalence axiom, which allows one to produce provably different proofs of equality.

**Edit** It is important to remember that there are two notions of equality in Coq: *definitional equality* (i.e., terms that are equal by simplification) and *propositional equality* (i.e., terms that we can relate by `=`). Definitionally equal terms are interchangeable for Coq, whereas propositionally equal terms must be exchanged with an explicit rewriting step (or using the `match` statement, as seen above).

I was a bit lax in the discussion above about the difference between these two variants. There are cases where proofs of equality are propositionally equal even if they aren't so definitionally. For instance, consider the following alternate proof of reflexivity for `nat`:

```
Fixpoint eq_refl_nat (n : nat) : n = n :=
  match n return n = n with
  | 0 => eq_refl 0
  | S n' => match eq_refl_nat n' in _ = m return S n' = S m with
            | eq_refl => eq_refl (S n')
            end
  end.
```

The term `eq_refl_nat` is *not* definitionally equal to `eq_refl`: we cannot obtain `eq_refl` from `eq_refl_nat` just by simplification. However, both are *propositionally* equal: as it turns out, for `nat`, it is possible to show that `forall n (e : n = n), e = eq_refl`. (As I mentioned above, this cannot be shown for arbitrary Coq types.)

Comment: Hi Arthur, thank you. This is exactly what I had in mind. May I interprete your answer with the **plus_n_0** function in that way, that the inside match term delivers an equality proof which is different form eq_refl?

Comment: Not quite; I'll add an explanation.

Comment: your function eq_refl_nat is an example for a function which is propositionally equal to eq_refl but not definitionall equal. Is my simpler function above, _fun x:nat => eq_refl x_, of the same kind?

Comment: No, because that is definitionally equal to `eq_refl`, although it relies on a feature that was added to Coq only recently: eta conversion. You can try to write `Check (eq_refl : (fun n : nat => eq_refl n) = @eq_refl nat)).`, which has the effect of testing whether two things are definitionally equal.

Comment: If I understand this correctly then definitional equality cannot be precisely defined but instead depends on the implementation. But I think, a minimum set of definitional equality must be defined, else it would not be possible to prove simple lemmas like, _forall x:nat, x+0=x_. Is that statement correct?

Comment: Definitional equality does _not_ depend on the implementation: it is a fundamental component of the type theory itself. In some systems (e.g., extensional type theory), definitional equality and propositional equality are conflated. This could lead you to believe that definitional equality is only a decidable approximation to propositional equality, but this is not true: there are systems (e.g., homotopy type theory) where conflating both notions leads to an inconsistent theory. Thus, definitional equality is in a sense a *stronger* notion of equality.

Comment: You said  that Coq has now eta conversion as part of definitional equality, which it had not in previous versions. From that I conclude that either eta conversion is not a strictly necessary part of definitional equality, or that the definitional equality implementation in previous versions of Coq was incomplete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102518/discussion-between-arthur-azevedo-de-amorim-and-cryptostasis).

Comment: Regarding "It should be possible to prove it formally by arguing that, since Coq's theory is strongly normalizing, " Coq's theory may be strongly normalizing, but Coq's implementation is not.  Closing a proof of equality with `Qed` will have it not reducing to eq_refl.  You can also break subject reduction using coinductive types, so I suspect you can use this to block equality reduction.